# HTML button to activate keyboard simulation

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, autohotkey

I would like to make 3 buttons to activate a simulated key press of "Alt+o", "Alt+w" and "Alt+c" inside HTML in Internet Explorer.

Explanation of what I want to do-
I have made a website that handles various things and now trying to activate a background program.  I have installed AutoHotKey and I can get these buttons to work with the keyboard but I want to run this without a keyboard attached.

I have found 2 other similar responses on here but I could not make them work and as they were older threads I thought I would start a new thread to see what is out there.

EDIT: I don't want pressing Alt+o key to trigger something (I already have that), I want the reverse, a button that triggers (simulates) Alt+o key combination

Comment: Would you link us to the old threads you've found.

Comment: These are the 2 I found-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857988/javascript-trigger-keypress-on-mouse-click-without-jquery and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727830/press-escape-key-on-keyboard-with-html-button

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that.

```
  $('<selector element>').keydown(function(e){
       var arrayOfCharcode=[111,99,119];//ascii codes need to be allowed
       if(e.altKey && arrayOfCharcode.indexOf(e.which)>=0){
          e.preventDefault();
           prompt("Alt+<charcode ascii>, Enter","text");
       }
   });
```

you can do that in your case

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
       var arrayOfCharcode=[99,111,119,68,79,87];//ascii codes need to be allowed
       if(e.altKey && arrayOfCharcode.indexOf(e.which)>=0){
          e.preventDefault();
          switch(e.which){
              case 99:
              case 68:
                    //call button1 function  alt + c
                break;
            case 111:
            case 79:
                    //call button2 function alt + o
                break;
            case 119:
            case 87:
                    //call button3 function alt +w
                break;
          }
       }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I just require 1 combination at a time per individual button.  I am guessing this does all 3 in a row.  To be more specific I am running a light program in the back ground and want Alt+o to turn off the lights (Which I can do with keyboard with the webpage on top)  the other 2 operate different light functions.  Is the first part - $('<selector element>') to be modified to link to a button (e.g. $('button1')? What is the prompt line for?

Comment: EDIT: I dont want pressing Alt+o key to trigger something, i want the reverse, something that triggers Alt+o key combination